# Contour integral $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos\theta} \cos⁡(n\theta+\sin\theta)~d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

In the book it was asked to evaluate the integral using the contour integration. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos\theta}  \cos⁡(n\theta+\sin\theta)~d\theta$$

I tried by putting $e^{i(n\theta+\sin\theta)}$ didn't get the answer correctly. The answer given by the book is $$(-1)^n\frac{2\pi}{n!}$$

Comment: You could try $\cos(n\theta + \sin\theta) = \Re (\cos(n\theta + \sin\theta) + i\sin(n\theta + \sin\theta))$.

Answer (score 5):

> $$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos\theta}  \cos⁡(n\theta+\sin\theta)~d\theta$$

$$I=\Re\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\cos\theta-i(n\theta+\sin\theta)}~d\theta=\Re\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-e^{i\theta}-in\theta}~d\theta=\Re\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-e^{i\theta}}}{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^n}~d\theta$$

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$

$$I=\Re\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-z}}{z^n}\frac{1}{iz}~dz=\Re\oint \frac{e^{-z}}{i\cdot z^{n+1}}~dz=\Re\left(2\pi i\cdot Res(z=0)\right)$$

Do Laurent series and take the coefficient for $z^{-1}$ term:

$$\frac{e^{-z}}{i\cdot z^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{i\cdot z^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!}z^k$$

we get

$$Res(z=0)=\frac{(-1)^n}{i\cdot n!}$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos\theta}  \cos⁡(n\theta+\sin\theta)~d\theta =\frac{2\pi\cdot (-1)^n}{ n!}$$

Comment: can you tell did you made cos(nθ+sinθ) into -i(nθ+sinθ) in power i know that you put cosθ into (e^iθ)+(e^-iθ)/2,then what happened to e^iθ?

Comment: which step do you refer to?

Comment: 2nd step and  does R mean real part?

Comment: Yes, it is real part @ShantuDhami

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos\theta}  \cos⁡(n\theta+\sin\theta)~d\theta\\
=& \int_0^{2\pi}e^{in \theta}\cdot e^{-e^{-i\theta}} d\theta
= \int_0^{2\pi}e^{in \theta}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-e^{-i\theta})^k}{k!}\ d\theta \\
=& \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-k)\theta}\ d\theta 
=\frac{2\pi(-1)^n}{ n!}
\end{align}
where only the $k=n$ term survives the integration.

Comment: Wonderful use of $e^{ix}$ made the computation much easer.